# Raw JavaScript appearing on MSO home page

Tags: bug

I'm seeing

```
docsHero.RenderPartial(Html); storyHero.RenderPartial(Html);
```

below the header on MSO.

...and a couple of minutes later it's appeared on SO too.

At the bottom of the page:

> rev 2017.4.6.25624